# Calcular ingreso mensual y por año con datos de mysql

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysqli

```html
<!-- Earnings (Monthly) Card Example -->
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
              <div class="card border-left-primary shadow h-100 py-2">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                    <div class="col mr-2">
                      <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-1">Ganancias (Mensual)</div>
                      <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">$</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                      <i class="fas fa-calendar fa-2x text-gray-300"></i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Earnings (Monthly) Card Example -->
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
              <div class="card border-left-success shadow h-100 py-2">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                    <div class="col mr-2">
                      <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-success text-uppercase mb-1">Ganancias (Anuales)</div>
                      <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">$</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                      <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign fa-2x text-gray-300"></i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Tengo estos secciones donde quiero calcular el ingreso mensual y por año con datos de mi bd, me imagino la secuencia mysql pero no como hacer que solo e muestre por ejemplo de solo octubre y al finalizar el mes se reinicie y calcule noviembre, espero su ayuda.[image: este es el diseño que uso.]

Comment: Necesitas ayuda con que cosa? con los querys? el codigo php? el codigo js? tu pregunta no muestra nada (ni siquiera a donde hay que hacer las consultas). Cual seria el problema que queres resolver?

Comment: Que tal christianfabela, te darás cuenta que el código que adjuntaste no corresponde con lo solicitado... lo que necesitas corresponde con la obtención de los datos y no con como lo vas a visualizar. Para poder ayudarte necesitamos ver código correspondiente a tu consulta en tu gestor, caso extremo tu código en PHP o Javascript... Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código relevante al caso...

Comment: Buen día necesito ayuda con el codigo php, eso es todo lo que tengo, no sé si haya una sentencia para como menciono al principio solo me muestre las ganancias de un mes y asi sucesivamente.